# Whatsapp Web utiliza Node.js?

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

Gostaria de saber quais as tecnologias usadas no desenvolvimento do Whatsapp Web.

Ps: Pergunta a nível de pesquisa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é utilizado NodeJS. No backend, o servidor utilizado é o Yaws, que é desenvolvido em Erlang, uma das primeiras linguagens completamente voltadas para aplicações concorrentes.

No front, não há uma tecnologia específica. Aparentemente, tudo é desenvolvido in-house. Nota-se apenas o uso de Material Design, flex-box (quando suportado), ReactJS, Modernizr (para identificar o que o browser suporta), MomentJS, VelocityJS nas animações.

Sobre editores, etc, acredito que não há um específico. O Facebook não restringe aos seus funcionários um editor ou IDE específico. Apenas o fluxo de testes e CI deles que é obrigatório (lembre-se que o Facebook comprou o WhatsApp).